# Red Hat Fuse - How to integrate Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I just started investigating Red Hat Fuse.
The thing I want to test is, I already have a simple Spring Boot REST API application and deployed and running in kubernetes cluster.

I want to recreate the same project with Red Hat Fuse, I went through the fuse documentation, didn't get clear idea.

1. How can I start with Fuse? Can I use existing spring project I have
   in Red Hat Fuse? Or do I need to redevelop the Spring Boot project
   with Apache Camel framework?
2. Can someone give the link that how can I run simple Spring Boot project in Red Hat Fuse

Answer (score 3):

There are Getting Started Guide and Fuse on OpenShift Guide. You can start from here:

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.5/html/getting_started/index
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.5/html/fuse_on_openshift_guide/index